# Evaluate mathematical expression with percentage

Tags: java, android, regex

I want evaluate the mathematical expression containing arithmetic operators, percentage and brackets

`e.g. expressionString = 200+10%+(50+100%)%`. The expected output `440`.

I am using `exp4j` library which handles mathematical expression as per BODMAS rule. But it does not have provision for calculating percentage so I have to write my own logic. I tried using following code

```
        Expression expression;
        String newExpr = "", exprResult = "";
        String[] ar;
        if (calHelper.containsScientific(expressionString)) {
            ar = expressionString.split("(?<=[-+])|(?=[-+])");  //split the expression with operator
        } else {
            ar = expressionString.split("(?<=[-+()])|(?=[-+()])"); //split the expression with operator
            //ar = expressionString.split("(?<=[-+])|(?=[-+])"); //split the expression with operator
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("exp: "+ar[i]);
            try {
                if (ar[i].indexOf('%') < 0) {
                    newExpr += ar[i];
                    expression = evaluateExpression(newExpr, radDeg.getText().toString());
                    ValidationResult res = expression.validate();
                    if (res.isValid()) {
                        double result = expression.evaluate();
                        exprResult = calHelper.withNoTrailingZeros(result);
                        newExpr = exprResult;
                    }
                } else {
                    //If there is addition/substraction of percent in given arithmetic
                    // then calculate % on calculated result, for all other operators get 1% value i.e. perNo/100
                    //If there is no second operand after % do not calculate and go as per exp4j calculation
                    int preIndex = i - 1, nextIndex = i + 1;
                    String prevOp, nextOp;
                    prevOp = preIndex > -1 ? ar[preIndex] : "";
                    nextOp = nextIndex < ar.length ? ar[nextIndex] : "";
                    String perNo = ar[i].replace("%", "");

                    if (!exprResult.isEmpty() && calHelper.isNumeric(perNo) &&
                            calHelper.percentNoSecondOperand(ar[i]) &&
                            calHelper.allowPercentCal(prevOp, nextOp)) {
                        newExpr += exprResult + '%' + perNo;
                        expression = evaluateExpression(newExpr, radDeg.getText().toString());
                        ValidationResult res = expression.validate();
                        if (res.isValid()) {
                            double result = expression.evaluate();
                            newExpr = calHelper.withNoTrailingZeros(result);
                            exprResult = newExpr;
                        }
                    } else if (calHelper.percentNoSecondOperand(ar[i]) &&
                            calHelper.allowOnePercentCal(perNo, prevOp, nextOp)) {
                        newExpr += ar[i].replaceAll("%", "%1");
                        expression = evaluateExpression(newExpr, radDeg.getText().toString());
                        ValidationResult res = expression.validate();
                        if (res.isValid()) {
                            double result = expression.evaluate();
                            newExpr = calHelper.withNoTrailingZeros(result);
                            exprResult = newExpr;
                        }
                    } else {
                        newExpr += ar[i];
                        expression = evaluateExpression(newExpr, radDeg.getText().toString());
                        ValidationResult res = expression.validate();
                        if (res.isValid()) {
                            double result = expression.evaluate();
                            newExpr = calHelper.withNoTrailingZeros(result);
                            exprResult = newExpr;
                        }

                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Above code works properly to calculate any percentage when there are no brackets but it fails when using brackets.

Is there is any java library which can handle the expression containing any combination of standard operators, brackets and percentage operator.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you give us more elaborate about the algorithm which you need? I don't clearly understand why did you split `200+10%` but not `(200+10%)%`.

Comment: Actually I want to split (200+10%)% also but I have no idea about how to handle it. So I mention the final output of string. I am using exp4j library which handles brackets but not percentage.

Comment: It's hard to say how to help if even you don't know how to handle cases in brackets. What for nested case `((200+10%)%+10%)%` for example? Do you want to split by operators only if you don't have percent after bracket? And what for standard numbers? `(200+10%)` or `(200+10)` should be split or not? I think you don't have a problem with splitting, but with evaluating that expression. You just need an algorithm to calculate mathematical expressions with percentages.

Comment: OK. I have changed the subject now & also paste the code. Please check and let me know for any possible solution.